# Unable to load required js file for my code using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Inside my main.js file:

```
define(['require'], function(require) {
    require([
        '../libs/requirejs/plugins/domReady',
        '../core',
        '../ndn.2',
        '../Ndn/Widget'
    ],
    function(domReady) {
        // require('../Ndn/Widget'); // I tried this too, but it doesn't solve my problem

        console.log('Should have required everything...');

        domReady(function() {
            console.log('About to call init()');

            init();
        });
    }
)});

function init() {
    // Begin fetching this widget's delivery settings
    Ndn_Widget.fetchDeliverySettings();

    // ... Other code here ...
}
```

In my Ndn/Widget.js file, I have the following:

```
var Ndn_Widget;

define(['require'], function(require) {
    require(['../ndn.2', './ServerInterface'], function() {
        /**
         * An associative array for the different delivery settings
         * @var Object
         */
        var deliverySettings = {};

        Ndn_Widget = {
            fetchDeliverySettings: function() {
                // ... code here
                console.log('Finished defining Ndn_Widget.');
            }
        };
    });
});
```

I am expecting that the anonymous function I pass to the define() function inside of main.js would only be executed after the "../Ndn/Widget.js" file has been loaded, but this is not always the case.

This is an example of my console.log statements:

```
Should have required everything...
About to call init()
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fetchDeliverySettings' of undefined 
Just finished defining Ndn_Widget.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While interacting with the global scope is reasonably frowned upon when using AMD, it is still doable.

I was requiring the `../Ndn/Widget` module and incorrectly expected its nested require() logic (shown below) to be executed **synchronously**:

```
require(['../ndn.2', './ServerInterface'], function() {
```

**The above logic however only executes asynchronously** (as "Asynchronous Module Definition" suggests). The following code within the `main` module...

```
    Ndn_Widget.fetchDeliverySettings();
```

was being executed without knowing if the nested require() logic had been executed yet within the `../Ndn/Widget` module.

One solution to fix this would be to introduce a new module that can be referred to by both modules, for example say an `app` module, that triggers an event to let the other module know that the global Ndn_Widget
variable is now defined.

**Updated main.js file:**

```
define(['require', 'app'], function(require, app) {
    require([
        '../libs/requirejs/plugins/domReady',
        '../core',
        '../ndn.2',
        '../Ndn/Widget'
    ],
    function(domReady) {
        console.log('Should have required everything...');

        app.on('ready', function() { // domReady(function() {
            console.log('About to call init()');

            init();
        });
    }
)});

function init() {
    // Begin fetching this widget's delivery settings
    Ndn_Widget.fetchDeliverySettings();

    // ... Other code here ...
}
```

**Updated Ndn/Widget.js file:**

```
var Ndn_Widget;

define(['app', 'require'], function(require, app) {
    require(['../ndn.2', './ServerInterface'], function() {
        /**
         * An associative array for the different delivery settings
         * @var Object
         */
        var deliverySettings = {};

        Ndn_Widget = {
            fetchDeliverySettings: function() {
                // ... code here
                console.log('Finished defining Ndn_Widget.');
            }
        };

        app.trigger('ready');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using the concept of `require` and `define` incorrectly.

- No need to define variables outside of your modules. Things should be
  returned from modules, not modified outside of them.
- Use `define` as
  it sounds, to define a chunk of code that serves a purpose. Think of
  these as your Classes if it helps
- Use `require` to grab your modules
  and get them to interact.

I've re-written your example to demonstrate

**main.js**

```
require([
    '../libs/requirejs/plugins/domReady',
    '../Ndn/Widget',
    '../core'
], function(domReady, Ndn_Widget) {

    domReady(function() {
        Ndn_Widget.fetchDeliverySettings();
    });

});
```

**Ndn/Widget.js**

```
define(function(require) {
    require('../ndn.2');
    require('./ServerInterface');

    var deliverySettings = {};

    return {
        fetchDeliverySettings: function() {

        }
    };
});
```

If your other dependencies aren't AMD modules, and you depend on their return values then you may need to use [the shim configuration option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) as well.

I would encourage you to re-read [the API docs on module definitions](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about using `require('...')` without a callback.  I would imagine this is usually not what you want.

Comment: I'm not, it's just the sugar syntax - http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar

Comment: Ah ok. Nice tip. It seemed a bit weird coming from my purely AMD background. Upvoted!

Comment: The new code for Ndn/Widget.js gives the following error:
`Uncaught Error: Module name "../ndn.2" has not been loaded yet for context: _`

Comment: You could probably remove it from main.js to be sure. Adjusted my code to reflect. It's also tricky as I'm not certain what `ndn.2` is in this case.

Comment: So, I'm using requirejs a little unconventionally due to my need to add modules into an existing application that has a lot of global functions defined in `ndn.2` js file. I'm trying to gradually introduce order where none existed before. What I'm expecting about how requirejs works is that it listens for an event that happens after the dependency JavaScript files have been loaded (and executed) it then executes the anonymous function paired with the JavaScript dependencies I provided it through the define() function.

Comment: Additionally, the `ndn.2` js file has no `define()` call using requirejs since some webpages may referencing this file without going through requirejs to begin with. I'm wondering if this is what is causing some issues...